# Why aren't nLog custom event properties rendering through an email target?

Tags: nlog

I have a facade I'm using to wrap up my nLog calls. I'm using nLog's event properties to add a custom "longMessage" field. Here is the code:

```
public void Fatal(string shortMessage, string longMessage, Exception exception = null)
{
    Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my custom value");
    theEvent.Message = shortMessage;
    theEvent.Properties["LongMessage"] = longMessage;
    theEvent.Exception = exception;
    _logger.Fatal(theEvent);
}
```

When I write nLog events to a file or to the database target, the LongMessage field renders correctly. But when I write to email, I get an empty string where my long message should be. Any ideas why outputting properties would work in a database target but not work in an email target?

```
<target name="themail" xsi:type="Mail"
    smtpServer="VALID.INTERNAL.IP"
    from="sender@address.com"
    to="recip@address.com"
    subject="${event-properties:item=LongMessage}"
    body="${all-event-properties:format=[key]=[value]:separator=,:includeCallerInformation=true}"
    html="true"
    encoding="UTF-8">
```

I get the email just fine. It comes in great. But the subject and body are just blank. I've added other things to the subject and body to make sure I'm getting something in the subject and body of the email, and that works too. Everything works except the event-properties lookup -- and that only doesn't work on the email target.

Comment: It should work. If it still not working, open an issue on https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape the equal sign in format - that's what I finally figured out:

```
${all-event-properties:format=[key]\=[value]:separator=,:includeCallerInformation=true}"
```